# How to click checkbox in VBA IE automation relatively(by providing data from excel cell)?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to get data from excel cell, for example contractID = 12345 and then click on checkbox corresponding to the contractID on the webpage through IE automation.

Below is the code i tried but its not working for me. I would really appreciate if someone could me out in this.

```
                                <table width="100%" class="datatable" id="tblFirst">
                                  <tr>
<td class="aligncenter"><input name="j_idt312:0:chkAsset" class="assetGroup" 
id="j_idt312:0:chkAsset" onclick="selectorOnlyOneAssetGroupPlan('0')" 
type="checkbox">
                            </td>
                                    <td><span class="outputText">619014</span>
                                </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td><span class="outputText">535171</span>
                                 </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
```

I need to fetch 619014 and click corresponding checkbox. This value would come from excel cell, so first it should search on the web and then check the checkbox.

```
         contractID = Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2"))
         Set ContractList = IE.Document.querySelectorAll("outputText").Item(i)
         For i = 0 To ContractList.Length - 1
         Debug.Print ContractList.Item(i).innerText
         If ContractList = "" & contractID & "" Then
         IE.Document.getElementById("checkbox").Click
         End If
         Next
```

Comment: Please check your code, from your code, it seems that you are using the span tag, instead of checkbox control, how do you display this checkbox and checked it?  Can you post related code to explain more details (you could also checked the checkbox and compare whether there have some difference)?

Comment: As updated in the html, I want to get checkbox element corresponding to the contractID i am searching on the page. Plus I need to loop through all the contract IDs on the page till i find the matching one and then i need to click on the checkbox placed beside it.Its in the same <tr>.

Answer (score 0):

We could use the [common VBA Methods](http://automatetheweb.net/common-vba-methods-properties-web-automation/) (such as: getElementById, getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName methods) to find the table and loop through the rows, then find the related checkbox and span elements, finally set the checkbox checked property. More detail steps, please check the following sample code:

VBA script (change the website url to your's):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "<web site url>"

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Dim contractID As String
        contractID = "535171"

        'find the table
        Set i = IE.Document.getElementById("tblFirst").getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)
        Debug.Print i.Rows.Length
        If i.Rows.Length > 0 Then

            'loop through the table rows.
            For Each rowItem In i.Rows

                'from the second td cell, find the outputtext value and compare the value.
                If rowItem.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByClassName("outputText")(0).innerText = contractID Then
                     'find the checkbox from the first td cell, and then checked the checkbox.
                     rowItem.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).getElementsByClassName("assetGroup")(0).Checked = True

                     'add debugger to check the checked item value
                     'Debug.Print rowItem.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText

                End If
            Next rowItem
        End If
    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Web page resource:

```
<table width="100%" class="datatable" id="tblFirst" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="aligncenter">
                <input name="j_idt312:0:chkAsset" class="assetGroup"
                       id="j_idt312:0:chkAsset"
                       type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td><span class="outputText">619014</span>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="aligncenter">
                <input name="j_idt312:0:chkAsset" class="assetGroup"
                       id="j_idt312:0:chkAsset"
                       type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td><span class="outputText">535171</span>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After running the VBA script, the output as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out with the code, I have one doubt. Why have you not declared rowItem, i in the code?Is there any reference i need to add to use them?Appreciate your help!

Comment: About the rowItem, since it is in the for each statement, you could use it without declaring it, but from [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-for-eachnext-statements), we could also declare it first, then using it in the for each statement. So, both of them are working well in the for each statement. Besides, about the reference, I just add the **Microsoft Internet Controls** reference on my side (using Excel 2016), please check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM6qL.png).

Comment: I tried your code, however, I am getting error "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: About the "Object variable or with block variable not set" error, which line will throw this error?you could add some debugger and step by step running the code, then find out it. Besides,here are some related articles about this issue, please check it:[Link1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set) and [Link 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91). If still not working, can you post enough code to reproduce the problem?